# strtok() が NULL を返した後、さらに strtok(NULL, ...) を呼んでもよいのか。

Tags: c

## 背景と質問

以下のようなプログラムを見掛けました。

```c
char *token1 = strtok(str, " ");
char *token2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
char *token3 = strtok(NULL, " ");

if(token1 == NULL) {
    // トークンがない場合の処理
}
else if(token2 == NULL) {
    // トークンが1個の場合の処理
    ...
}
else if(token3 == NULL) {
    // トークンが2個の場合の処理
    ...
}
else {
    // トークンが3個以上の場合の処理
    ...
}
```

このプログラムでは、`strtok()` が一度 `NULL` を返した後、続けて `strtok(NULL, ...)` を呼ぶことができる、ということが前提になっています。
こういった使い方は今まで思い付かず、考えたことがない、というより無意識のうちに未定義と思い込んでいたのですが、このような使い方は規格上保証されているものなのでしょうか。

## 規格調査

検証のために、規格を調べてみました。
ISO/IEC 9899:2011 の 7.24.5.8 The `strtok` function から引用します (強調は引用者による)。
この引用中の `s1`、`s2` は、それぞれ `strtok` の第1引数、第2引数を表します。

> 3
>   The first call in the sequence searches the string pointed to by `s1` for the first character
>   that is not contained in the current separator string pointed to by `s2`. If no such character
>   is found, then there are no tokens in the string pointed to by `s1` and the **`strtok` function
>
>   returns a null pointer**. If such a character is found, it is the start of the first token.
>
> 4
>   The `strtok` function then searches from there for a character that is contained in the
>   current separator string. If no such character is found, the current token extends to the
>   end of the string pointed to by `s1`, and **subsequent searches for a token will return a null
>
>   pointer**. If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character, which
>   terminates the current token. **The `strtok` function saves a pointer to the following
>
>   character**, from which the next search for a token will start.
>
> 5
>   Each subsequent call, with a null pointer as the value of the first argument, starts
>   searching from the saved pointer and behaves as described above.

この記述について、以下のように場合分けして考えてみました。

ここで、パラグラフ5の書き方は曖昧に感じましたが、`strtok(NULL, ...)` 呼び出しについては、パラグラフ3と4の `s1` を パラグラフ4で保存したポインタに置き換えて実行する、という意味であると解釈しました。

### ケース1: `s1` = `"abc def"` のように、トークン文字で終わる場合

`"def"` が返った後の呼び出しで、パラグラフ 4 の「subsequent **searches** for a token will return a null pointer」のパターンに合致し、`NULL` が返ります。「search」が複数形となっているため、何度 `strtok(NULL, ...)` を呼んでも `NULL` が返ります。

### ケース2: `s1` = `"abc def "` のように、トークン列の末尾に区切り文字がある場合

`"def"` が返った後の呼び出しで、パラグラフ 3 の「`strtok` function returns a null pointer」のパターンに合致し、`NULL` が返ります。何かしら保存したポインタ (このケースでは文字列末尾) があり、そのポインタのアップデートがないため、何度呼んでもパラグラフ3のパターンに合致して `NULL` が返ります。

### ケース3: `s1` = `" "` のように、トークン列がない場合

前項と同様、パラグラフ3のパターンに合致して `NULL` が返ります。この場合、保存したポインタというものがないため、**後続の `strtok(NULL, ...)` は未定義になりそう**です。

以上、場合によっては `NULL` が返った後の `strtok(NULL, ...)` は `NULL` が返り、別の場合では未定義になりそうに思えました。
しかし、それでは何とも中途半端で気持ち悪く感じます。
これをどう考えるか、ということで、以下の2通りの可能性を考えました。

- 上記の解釈に間違いがあり、`NULL` が返るか未定義かはどちらか一方に定まる。
- 基本的に未定義と考えるべき。パラグラフ4で 「search」が複数形になっていることに特に意味はない。

しかし、何が正しいのかという確証は取れませんでした。

## 実験

参考までに、手持ちの環境ではどうなのか実験してみました。

### 環境:

- OS: Gentoo Linux
- コンパイラ: gcc 4.8.4, clang 3.5.0
- ライブラリ: glibc 2.20

### プログラム:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// トークンの内容を出力。ただし NULL の場合は "(null)" を出力。
#define PR_TOKEN(token)  do { printf(#token " = %s\n", (token)? token: "(null)"); } while(0)

int main(void)
{
    // ケース1: 文字列がトークン文字で終わる
    char str1[] = "abc def";
    char *token1_1 = strtok(str1, " ");
    char *token1_2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char *token1_3 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char *token1_4 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    PR_TOKEN(token1_1);
    PR_TOKEN(token1_2);
    PR_TOKEN(token1_3);
    PR_TOKEN(token1_4);

    // ケース2: 文字列が区切り文字で終わる
    char str2[] = "abc def ";
    char *token2_1 = strtok(str2, " ");
    char *token2_2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char *token2_3 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char *token2_4 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    PR_TOKEN(token2_1);
    PR_TOKEN(token2_2);
    PR_TOKEN(token2_3);
    PR_TOKEN(token2_4);

    // ケース3: トークン列がない
    char str3[] = " ";
    char *token3_1 = strtok(str3, " ");
    char *token3_2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char *token3_3 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char *token3_4 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    PR_TOKEN(token3_1);
    PR_TOKEN(token3_2);
    PR_TOKEN(token3_3);
    PR_TOKEN(token3_4);

    return 0;
}
```

### 結果:

```
token1_1 = abc
token1_2 = def
token1_3 = (null)
token1_4 = (null)
token2_1 = abc
token2_2 = def
token2_3 = (null)
token2_4 = (null)
token3_1 = (null)
token3_2 = (null)
token3_3 = (null)
token3_4 = (null)
```

すべてのケースについて、一度 `NULL` が返った後の `strtok()` 呼び出しで `NULL` が返っています。
今回、正当性について疑問が残るケース3について、ケース1 、ケース2で保存していた情報が残っているため、たまたまうまく動いている、ということを疑い、ケース3のみを実行したり、ケース2の最初の `strtok()` 呼び出しの直後にケース3に入ってみても同様でした。

Answer (score 4):

> 7
>   The strtok function returns a pointer to the first character of a token, or a null pointer if there is no token.

とありますので、該当するトークンがない場合にはNULLを返すと考えて良いと思います。

参考までに、
Ｃリファレンスマニュアル第５版の解説によると、

> すべての文字がsetに属していればstrtokはナルポインタを返し内部状態ポインタをナルポインタに設定する．

とありますので、ケース３の場合も内部ポインタがナルに設定される。のが質問者の想定と違います。
また、

> strと内部状態ポインタが共にナルポインタであれば，strtokはナルポインタを返し，内部状態ポインタはそのままにする．（すべての字句を返してもなおstrtokが呼ばれた時の備えである）

（※strは第一引数setは第２引数のこと）
とあるので、
「strtok() が一度 NULL を返した後、続けて strtok(NULL, ...) を呼ぶことができる」
は、前提としてよく、NULLを返すということになります。

Comment: パラグラフ7の解釈において、トークンがある/ない以前の問題として、一度`NULL` が返った後の `strtok(NULL, ...)` は、どこからトークンを探すのか、という疑問があります。
Cリファレンスマニュアルのような挙動が規格化されているなら問題ありませんけど、内部ポインタが回答のように設定される記述が規格に見付けられません。もしかして他のTR等関連文書？(そちらは未チェック)

Comment: @yoh2  逆説的になりますうが、トークンが無い（既にない）場合ＮＵＬＬを返すという仕様動作から保持ポインタをＮＵＬＬにしておくという実装が想定されます。（「一度NULL が返った後」のような場合分けの）説明が無いということはそういうコトだと思います。ライブラリ関数の動作説明については、大抵の場合未定義になる場合の動作が説明されています。そういう意味でも、未定義になるような動作はしないと思われます。私はＣ１１処理系を使っていないので確認できませんが、`strtok_s`で保持用ポインタを渡す仕様になっているので、保持用ポインタがどのように処理されるかは確認できるかもしれません。

Comment: 後でちょっと考えてみたら、保持用ポインタについては、トークンが無くなった時、ＮＵＬＬでなくても`'\0'`を指していてもいいような気がします（つまり次のスタート文字が文字列の終端ならば既に文字列は終端しているとＮＵＬＬでなくてもわかる）。そういう意味では、strtok_sで確認しようとするのは意味が無いかも知れません。（実装による）

Comment: 私的にな解釈としては、「トークンがない」という状態は保持ポインタが`'\0'`を指しているにせよＮＵＬＬになっているにせよ、それらの状態は既に「トークンがない」ということを表しているので、NULLを返すということです。「トークンがある/ない以前の問題」というのは変だと思います。

Comment: 「トークンがある/ない以前の問題」があるとしたら、最初のコールが`strtok(NULL, デリミタ);`のようにいきなり呼び出した場合には、（ルール違反なので）状態未定義だとは思います。そういう状況を防止する実装としては保持ポインタをＮＵＬＬで初期化し、トークンが無くなった場合にＮＵＬＬにしておくというのが良い実装かなと個人的には思います。

Comment: 「'\0'を指しているにせよＮＵＬＬになっているにせよ、それらの状態は既に「トークンがない」‌​ということを表している」
とのことですが、私は検索先にトークンがないということ (検索対象が空だったり、すべて区切り文字だったり) と、検索先がない (保持ポインタが不定だったり `NULL` だったり) は異なるもの、と思っています。もしこのふたつを、特に注釈なく同義に捉えてよいのなら、例えば `strchr()` の第1引数に `NULL` を指定するのは許容され、常に `NULL` が返るはずです。

Comment: 追記。「トークンがある/ない以前の問題」とは、検索先がない、という状態を指しています。

Comment: @yoh2   `""` とかデリミタのみの文字列の場合 `If no such character is found, the current token extends to the
end of the string pointed to by s1` 文字列終端(文字列の最後の次つまり終端文字である`'\0'`)を指していると考えていいかと思いますが。

Comment: 私が、`strtok(NULL, ...)` を続けて呼び出せるのか問題視しているのは、質問分のケース3の場合。つまり、最初から文字列がデリミタか空文字列のみの場合です。この場合、パラグラフ4の該当部分に到達せずに`NULL`が返されてしまいますよね。

Comment: ん？ もしかして、最初からトークンがない場合、パラグラフ3で`NULL`を返すとは書いているけど、それは単なる注記として置いておき、その場合でもパラグラフ4に書かれている動作を行う、と解釈するべきなのではないか、と今思い付きました。

Comment: @yoh2  `"\t\t\t"` でデリミタが`"\t"`で、トークンが無かったとする場合文字列の最後まで読む（走査する)必要があります(次の走査開始位置は`'\0'`の位置にできる)よね？

Comment: はい、その結果、パラグラフ3の. 「If no such character
is found, then there are no tokens in the string pointed to by s1 and the strtok function returns a null pointer. 」に従って `NULL` が返され、パラグラフ4の動作を行わないのではないかと考えていました。

Comment: @yoh2  最初から全部次のトークンがない場合と、途中から次のトークンが無くなった場合で動作を分ける必要はないと思います。つまり、３であり４の動作をする（どちらも動作説明）と考えられると思います。４はセカンドコールでの動作ともされていないし。

Comment: パラグラフ3と4は最初の呼び出しかそれ以降か、ではなく、3:トークンの先頭探し、4:トークンの末尾探し、だと思います。で、先頭が見付からない場合、そこで`NULL`を返すとパラグラフ3に記述されているのにもかかわらず、4もさらに行うのか、というところが気になっていた(というか、行わないと思っていた)わけです。

Comment: @yoh2  「末尾探し」ああ、そうですね。つまり、次回開始位置の設定をするのかしないのかってことですよね。結局のところトークンが無い場合は文字列を`\0`まで全部走査する必要があり、走査用のポインタ（次の走査開始位置）はトークンが無かった場合文字列の終端`\0`を指しているわけですしそれで**次回呼び出し時に既にトークンが無かったとわかる**。というのが私の主張です。普通に考えて`\0`に到達した場合にポインタをNULL以外の他のアドレス（動作未定義になるようなアドレス）に設定しなおすのも変な話だと思います。